# T-SQL- Recursive query- employee hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hierarchy, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I want to use recursive query (it can be `cte` or anything) where I am trying to pull the executive report - where I input one employee name and I want all the hierarchy related to that employees starting with the top level emloyee (starting with CEO) and then going down.

For example:

If I input the employee name `Celia`, the report should look like:

```
CEO
Employees reporting to CEO , let's say MgrX
Employees reporting to MgrX- let's say MgrY
Employees reporting to MgrY - let's say MgrZ
```

All the Employees reporting to `MgrZ` including `Celia` (input parameter).

The query I am trying to use :

```
            with cte1 as 
            (

            select 
            pa.PERSNBR
            ,pa.AUTHCD
            ,pu.VALUE
            ,hr.File#
            ,hr.[Payroll Name]
            ,hr.[Reports To File#]
            ,hr.[Reports To Name]
            ,hr.[EMC #]
            ,hr.[EMC Name]

            from 
                    [DNA_Staging].[dbo].[PERSAUTH] pa
            join    [DNA_Staging].[dbo].[PERSEMPL] pe
                on  pa.PERSNBR = pe.PERSNBR
            join    [DNA_Staging].[dbo].[PERSUSERFIELD] pu
                on  pe.PERSNBR = pu.PERSNBR
                and pu.USERFIELDCD = 'EFNR'
                and GETDATE() < isnull(pe.inactivedate,getdate()+1)
              join  [HR_Staging].[dbo].[HR_EmployeeHierarchyStaging] hr
                on  pu.VALUE = substring(hr.File#,2,6)
                or  pu.VALUE = substring(hr.File#,3,6)

                ),

                -- find all the data for input payroll name in the parameter
                cte2 as (select *
                FROM cte1 where [Payroll Name] = 'Acain, Celia T'),
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Tip: It should include a question.

Answer (score 0):

A basic example for your question (you haven't provide any data samples or output examples, so...):

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(20) = 'Darkwater'

;WITH emplevels AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'CEO'),
(2, 'MgrX'),
(3, 'MgrY'),
(4, 'MgrZ')
) as t(eid, who)
),
people AS ( --people and there levels
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'Smith', 1),
(2, 'Wake', 2),
(3, 'Cartman', 3),
(4, 'Sanders', 4),
(5, 'MacCormic', 1),
(6, 'Malkovich', 2),
(7, 'Whatever', 2),
(8, 'Darkwater', 3),
(9, 'Leto', 4)
) as t(pid, name, eid)
),
dep AS ( --dependences of levels
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1,1), --CEO - CEO
(1,2), --CEO - MgrX
(2,3), --MgrX - MgrY
(3,4)  --MgrY - MgrZ
)as t(eid1,eid2)
),
hier as ( -- get the hierarchy 
SELECT  d.eid1,
        d.eid2
FROM dep d 
LEFT JOIN people p ON d.eid2 = p.eid
where name = @name
UNION ALL
SELECT  d.eid1,
        d.eid2
FROM dep d
INNER JOIN hier h ON d.eid2 = h.eid1 
WHERE d.eid2 != d.eid1
)
--here comes heads and who there are
SELECT  p.name AS Head,
        e.who AS WhoIs
from hier h
LEFT JOIN people p ON p.eid = h.eid1
LEFT JOIN emplevels e ON e.eid = p.eid
ORDER BY e.eid
```

Result for `Darkwater` (he is `MgrY`). We have all `MgrX` and `CEO`'s:

```
Head      WhoIs
--------- -----
Smith     CEO
MacCormic CEO
Wake      MgrX
Malkovich MgrX
Whatever  MgrX

(5 row(s) affected)
```